# Python: fastest way to write/download online images to disk?

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, file-writing

How I can speed up the speed at which my program writes an online image to disk? Right now ~150KB takes ~8 seconds to download, 3 seconds for opening the image online and 5 seconds to write it.
Currently I'm doing it like this:

```py
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
request = get_request('link.to.image')
online_image = br.open(request)
with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(online_image.read())
```

What can I do to speed this up? And is there a way to write to disk as the image is being opened?

Comment: Optimal reading of large binary objects over HTTP(S) is done by streaming then reading the response content in chunks

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/download-large-file-in-python-with-requests